# Como usar REST para validar o recebimento de XML via POST

Tags: rest, restful, symfony, php-5

Eu tenho uma aplicação em Delphi que **envia um XML com um código via Post**. Eu tenho que desenvolver uma aplicação em Symfony que precisa validar o recebimento desse XML via post. Ouvir dizer que seria via Rest mas eu nunca usei Rest.

Gostaria de uma orientação ou orientação para Symfony 3 e de preferência em português.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua pergunta é bastante ampla, então vou explicar "por cima" o que você pode fazer, se a ideia é realmente utilizar Symfony 3:

1. crie seu projeto Symfony 3 com o comando `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition <nome-do-projeto>`; isso criará um projeto com diversas dependências básicas para a maioria dos projetos web (Doctrine, Swiftmailer, Twig etc);
2. crie uma classe `AppBundle\Entity\Data` com os dados que você irá receber (coloquei um exemplo mais abaixo);
3. modifique a única rota para receber os dados da requisição e mapeá-los para a classe criada acima.
4. Habilite o serviço `serializer` em seu `config.yml` (exemplo abaixo);
5. rode seu projeto com o comando `bin/console server:start`
6. teste a rota com uma requisição `POST` por meio do [HTTPie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie): `echo '<data><tag>oi</tag></data>' | http 127.0.0.1:8000/`

Arquivo `config.yml`:

```
framework:
    serializer:
        enabled: true
```

(ps: não é necessário excluir todas as configurações da chave `framework`, apenas adicione a configuração do `serializer`).

Classe `AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Data;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $this->getSerializer()->deserialize($request->getContent(), Data::class, 'xml');
        print_r($data); die;
    }

    /**
     * @return SerializerInterface
     */
    private function getSerializer()
    {
        return $this->get('serializer');
    }
}
```

Classe `AppBundle\Entity\Data`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Data
{
    public $tag;
}
```

Se tudo deu certo, você terá uma instância da classe `AppBundle\Entity\Data` preenchida com os dados recebidos via `POST`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.22

AppBundle\Entity\Data Object
(
    [tag] => oi
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Meu caro, nesse caso não tem uma receita de bolo, o ideal é que você vá até a documentação do Symfony (https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html) e dê uma olhada no que o framework disponibiliza para você.

Como no seu caso é um API REST, recomendo fortemente o uso do micro-framework baseado em Symfony chamado **Silex** (http://silex.sensiolabs.org/). Por se tratar de um micro-framework, ele é bem mais enxuto, trazendo o essencial para se construir um API Rest com um stack poderoso.

Obs: Os links estão em inglês, mas não tem como fugir disso. Boa sorte!